# How to select rows having values equal to a unqiue value in another dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as follows:

df1:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 |
| def | 22 |
| def | 32 |
| aac | 53 |
| ddf | 53 |
| tefg | 53 |

df2:

| col1 |
| --- |
| ABC |
| def |
| aac |
| ddf |
| tefg |

Now I want to retain rows in df1, such that value of column "col1" in df1, is present in df2 "col2"

Is there a simple straightforward way to achieve it in Python?

Currently, I am doing it in a brute way with 2 nested for loops, but it is computationally intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df1[df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)]
```

**Example:**

Create `df1`:

```
data = {'col1': ['a','b','c','d'],
        'col2': [1,2,3,4]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and `df2`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a','d']})
```

then `df1[df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)]` will be:

```
  col1  col2
0    a     1
3    d     4
```

Comment: what is `df` in here?

Comment: Sorry, typo, edited my answer.